# How to open and work on files stored in Google drive from Google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

So I cannot successfully install miniconda and decided to work in Google Colab. But my local repository is in Google Drive. All of the jupyter notebook that I want to work on is store in Google Drive. I want to work on them in Google Colab. However, I cannot open the files other than the ones stored in Colab folder of Google drive. What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: Strange. I can access all files. what kind of error you are noticing? After mounting Gdrive, were you able to change directory, and do some other operations like zipping, saving files into other folders etc.

Comment: When I pressed open notebook, there were several options for where I can get files, Google Drive is there but when I click on it, it only show the files which are stored in the colab folder

Comment: Can you show the steps to navigate the entire google drive folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to mount google drive and then

   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
2. Click the link on colb and authenticate (copy password and paste in colab) to mount and access your gdrive.
3. You can access your folder as shown below
   path_to_data = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/MyFolder_where_data_stored'
   Unique_Labels_List = os.listdir(path_to_data)
4. After running model, save the model, zip and download to local.
   !zip -r ./MyFolder.zip /content/MyFolder
   files.download("/content/MyFolder.zip")

There are many other things you can do. Check [this resource](https://rohitmidha23.github.io/Colab-Tricks/) for some more commands and you can find many more by searching in google. Thanks!

Comment: What if instead of running the files that I got in Google drive, I want to modify them? How would I open then as ipynb file?

Comment: When you run colab in your drive, i guess it will update automatically in the drive when you close the file. I have never check it but all the .ipynb files are by default stored in `colab Notebooks` folder. You can also create a GitHub gist and share with other people if you want.

Comment: I have the same problem: I’ve cloned a git repo on my google drive and I need to access the notebooks which are stored in subfolders (because they use local python libs which are also stored in these subfolders). Cannot open the notebooks either from Colab. I think this answer doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

What works for me is opening the notebook from Google Drive, not from Colab.

The following steps:

- Open Google Drive in your browser, go to the notebook (ipynb) file in your repo (sub)folder;
- Right-click the file and select 'Open with Google Colaboratory', now Colab opens with the notebook;

  - For this you might have to install the 'Open in Colab' chrome extension
- Mount Google Drive from Colab (if not mounted yet), see code snippet;
- Change directory to the folder where you want to run your notebook, see code snippet;
- Now I can run my notebook

Mount drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Change directory to your repository folder:

```
%cd drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/(YOUR_REPO_PATH)
```

Answer (score 2):

To open and work a notebook in your Google drive, open it from Google Drive UI in Chrome. From the Google colab UI menu -> **Open notebook**, we can only open those in **Colab Notebooks** folder.

Easy way would be to save all your notebooks in the  **Colab Notebooks** folder.

[image]