# Does the Google COLAB folder in Google Drive not support subfolders?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, subdirectory

This may be the dumbest question ever, but here goes.  I cannot get COLAB to open a folder within the COLAB folder of Google Drive.  Is no folder organization allowed in the colab folder?  How do I organize colab notebooks so that every notebook is not in the same google drive directory?

Most similar questions are concerned with importing data or other files into a particular notebook.  That is not my concern.  I want to organize separate colab notebooks.  But, trying to open in colab anything other than an actual notebook file throws an error instead of, say, opening a subfolder with notebooks stored in it.

What am I missing?!?

Comment: May be you didn't mount your gdrive. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428443/how-to-open-and-work-on-files-stored-in-google-drive-from-google-colab/61433539#61433539

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  I have mounted the drive.  And, that allows me to see my folders and files in the side window.  However, I cannot open a notebook in a subfolder.  For example, if I choose File, Open Notebook, and then in the pop up window navigate to "Google Drive" I can see anything in the folder "Colab Notebooks."  However, if I click on a subfolder in "Colab Notebooks," colab tries to open the folder as if it were a notebook and throws an error.  I'm trying to create subfolders in "Colab Notebooks" that I can navigate to open a notebook.