# Unable to open python file using google colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am unable to open python file using google colab in google drive.I tried to open python file using google colab but it's not responding and showing error. I want to open that file and start my work. Please help to resolve my query.

Comment: Take a look here to see if this resolves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428443/how-to-open-and-work-on-files-stored-in-google-drive-from-google-colab

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python file in the drive by following steps below:

1. mount the drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2. Copy the path of the Python file that you want to run:
   [image]

3. Run the file

```
%run /content/drive/MyDrive/test.py
```

Note:

1. Inorder to open the py file just double-click on it
2. Alternative and simple option is to just copy and paste the py code on the cell